# How to target object coordinates after zoom using fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Currently I am trying to create connectors between objects added on the canvas. This works as intended for the default zoom.

After the default zoom changes I cannot target the correct coordinates of the objects. I tried using setCoords() after each zoom action but with no success.

See the fiddle bellow for details:

```
canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1 ) ;

for (var i in objects) {
  objects[i].setCoords();
}

canvas.renderAll();
canvas.calcOffset();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sgeax159/

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sgeax159/3/

Trying to draw things using oCoords is generally wrong.

oCoords are for mouse interaction and updated with setCoords().

setCoords() is called most of the time by fabric at the end of mouse interactions.

Trying to guess the canvas absolute coordinates from oCoords when there is zoom and pan is possible, but requires:

- to udpate oCoords manually called setCoords for all objects after zoom and pan
- to multiply the coords by the inverse of the viewportTransform

Fabric since 1.7.X offers aCoords that are the absolute coords of the objects, independent of the zoom level or the pan. Those sets of coordinates are very usefull for this kind of operation.

Sadly they come just for the four main corners ( tl, tr, bl, br ) but you can figure out the middle ones by adding and dividing:

ml is  `x = (tl.x + bl.x) / 2  and y = (tl.x + bl.y) / 2` or you can extend calcCoords to add them to calculation.

check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I figured is that you get the coordinates that are zoomed already but when you add the line to the canvas, the canvas applies the zoom the second time. It's hard to figure this out because canvas.zoomToPoint also gets in the middle.

So to see this comment the lines with canvas.zoomToPoint but leave the canvas.setZoom. You should still see your canvas zooming. Now in the connect function you have to reverse the zoom before adding the line, so you can modify the function like this:

```
  var lineCoordinates = [
                source.oCoords.mr.x / canvas.getZoom(),
                source.oCoords.mr.y / canvas.getZoom(),
                target.oCoords.ml.x / canvas.getZoom(),
                target.oCoords.ml.y / canvas.getZoom()
            ];
```

You'll see that without the interference of canvas.zoomToPoint this works as expected.

I think that in the case of canvas.zoomToPoint a translation is added to the coordinates that is also applied when you add the line. What I'd recomend is keep your objects in fixed space and don't use the coordinates of fabric.js. Let fabric only do the rendering, not the management of your objects. Hope this helps!

LATER EDIT: I found a more generic solution. So, in the connect function you add the following lines (var lineCoordinates is for context):

```
    savedZoom = canvas.getZoom();
    canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), 1.0);
    var lineCoordinates = [
```

And at the end of the function after you've added your objects, you restore the zoom:

```
canvas.add(line);
canvas.add(line.triangle);
canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), savedZoom);
```

This should work with both zoom functions (if you do a setZoom you just have to reset the zoom to 1 before adding your objects and then restore the saved value after you've added the objects).